# How to convert date format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I have a datepicker which works, but I am trying to convert it to a date object so that i could getDay from it. Problem is everytime i convert it, it gives me the wrong format, as in it will be MM/dd/yy, rather than dd/MM/yy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=txtDateTime.ClientID%>').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(new Date(Date.parse(date))); //this keeps giving month/day/year
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use datepicker's [parseDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) parse the custom formatted date

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate( 'dd/mm/yy', date)
            alert(dt.getDate()); 
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3pz4/)

Answer (score 0):

The `Date.parse` method is implementation dependent.
`new Date(string)` is equivalent to `Date.parse(string)`.

I would recommend to parse the date string manually, and use the Date constructor with the year, month and day arguments to avoid ambiguity:

```
// parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
```